# Android: Using the ParcelFileDescriptor returned from UiAutomation.executeShellCommand() in InstrumentationTestCase

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-uiautomator

I've written a generic `shellCommand` function for my `InstrumentationTestCase` subclass. The call to `executeShellCommand` works (the command is executed), but I'm doing something wrong with the returned `ParcelFileDescriptor`, because it seems to return rubbish. Here's my generic `shellCommand` function -

```
public String shellCommand(String str)
{
    UiAutomation uia = getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation();
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
    FileDescriptor fd;
    InputStream is;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    String outputString = null;

    try
    {
        pfd = uia.executeShellCommand(str);
        fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fd));
        is.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        outputString = buf.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("shellCommand: buf '%s'",outputString));
        is.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "shellCommand: failed to close fd");
    }
    return outputString;
}
```

And here's a snippet showing me calling it -

```
String output = shellCommand("ls -al /");
Log.d(TAG, String.format("root dir = {%s}", output));
```

I was hoping to receive the command's output string (in this example, a list of top-level directories). Instead I see the following log -

> shellCommand: buf '[B@1391fd8d'

I'm not great with Java, I just use it to write some automated tests. I'm obviously doing something wrong with the `ParcelFileDescriptor` or `BufferedInputStream`, can someone please explain what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method doesn't actually convert the contents of a byte array to a String. It returns "a string representation of the object". In this case, '[B@1391fd8d' means "the byte array whose hashcode is 1391fd8d" - not very useful is it?

You can convert a byte[] to a String by using the new [String(byte[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])) constructor.

However it's probably easier to use [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) to get a String directly from each line of output.

Comment: Thanks Allen! That's fixed it. I'd previously used `int.toString()` and just assumed that `byte[].toString()` would behave in the same way.